# Terminal does nothing after I run the program and enter the input. I have to press Ctrl+C before I even type anything on terminal

Tags: c, terminal

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float basic, da, hra, total;
    printf("Enter basic salary: ");
    scanf("%f ", &basic);
    da = 0.4 * basic;
    hra = 0.2 * basic;
    total = basic + da + hra;
    printf("Ramesh total salary is = %f", total);
    return 0;
}
```

**The compiler shows no error and when I enter the salary there is no output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL3fG.png)**

Comment: please do only tag the language you are using. This looks like C

Comment: Take some time to think about that trailing space in the `scanf` format string. What do you think it does?

Comment: The trailing whitespace in the `scanf()` format string tells it to filter *any amount* of whitespace, but the function won't know how much that is until you actually enter a non-whitespace character. Every character in the format string has a purpose.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I removed that trailing space in scanf an program worked. But I still have no idea why trailing space was causing that problem. Sir can you please elaborate why trailing space caused the problem

Comment: Please see previous comment, and *read the duplicate*.